# Getting integer in HashMap without Iterating

Tags: java

If I have:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Am I able to get all Strings based off an integer without iterating through the whole HashMap? If this isn't possible, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I don't get your question.  What's the matter with `hm.keySet()`?

Comment: Yes, you will have to iterate over the values in order to get the associated keys.

Comment: I need to get all String values in the HashMap using the Integer without Ilteration. If this isn't possible, I need the best and quickest way to Ilterate through the whole thing

Comment: The only way to avoid iteration in a Map is to *know the key*. It may be relevant to also maintain a *reverse map* if the keys and values are distinct (or to reverse the original map and use it accordingly).

Comment: What is 'using the Integer'?

Comment: @markspace I need to get all string associated with an int, ie, if I have "Pie", "1" - "Apple", "1" - "Fruit", 2, I need to be able to specify "1" and get Pie and Apple back

Comment: OK you want to find all Strings mapped to a given integer.  No, with this HashMap, you have to iterate through the whole thing.  There is no other way.

Comment: You might want to rethink your data structure.  Instead of a `Map<String, Integer>`, consider a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'd have to iterate over the contents of that map to get an integer for a string.  The reason for that is that you have your *key* set to be the arbitrary string you want, and the *value* is the integer you're searching on.

If you had the integer, you could iterate over the entry set instead:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.value().equals(searchValue) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

But this kind of takes the idea of using a map for this and turns it on its head.

Think of it like a dictionary.  Treat the word and the definition as a key and a value, respectively.  If you know the word you want to look up, then you're provided the value relatively quickly - it's in alphabetic order.

But, how do you search the dictionary if all you know is the definition?  You'd have to look at **every definition** until you came across the exact one you had, and *then* you could get the key from it.

The same thing is happening here. Instead of using an index to search your data structure, you're now going over every possible value inside of it to fetch a particular key.

For larger data sets, this is completely untenable.

I would recommend a [`BiMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) from Google Guava, with a few caveats:

- Both keys *and* values must be unique
- Consider that this may be overkill for what you want to do; it may be simpler to reverse the key-value pairing and use the integer as your key instead.

Also, per your comments, you may even want to look into a [`Multimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) instead.  It allows you to provide one key for multiple, different values, which may fit the use case you're trying to go for.

Here's an example implementation:

```
    Multimap<Integer, String> dataSet = HashMultimap.create();

    dataSet.put(1, "foo");
    dataSet.put(1, "bar");
    dataSet.put(1, "baz");

    // prints [baz, bar, foo]
    System.out.println(dataSet.get(1));
```

Comment: Reversing the key-value thing would not work due to there being multiple same values. I'm using this to store a team number a player is assigned to.

Comment: +1 to using a `Multimap`. Depending on the use case, [`Multimaps.invertFrom`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom(com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M)) and/or [`ImmutableMultimap.inverse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#inverse()) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with a `HashMap` other than iterating.

The data structure you want is typically called a bi-directional map, or `BiMap` -- this allows you to map both from *keys* to *values* (from `String` to `Integer`, in your case) but also back from *values* to *keys* (from `Integer` to `String`). This only works if your key-value mappings are unique, since your values are now also keys as well.

The Google Guava library has a [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface and [several implementations](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) to choose from.

**Edit:** Given your comment:

> I need to get all string associated with an int, ie, if I have "Pie", "1" - "Apple", "1" - "Fruit", 2, I need to be able to specify "1" and get Pie and Apple back

What you actually want is a [`Multimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap)`<Integer, String>`. Depending on the use case, [`Multimaps.invertFrom`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom(com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M)) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a subset of your keys, that "share" the same key value using a hashmap that way.

To get the data, you coud use `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>` as construction.